# Getting value of specific key in a dictionary

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so:

```
li = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'benana', 'c': 'cherry'}
```

So I have:

```
>>> for key, value in li.items():
...     print key, value
... 
a apple
c cherry
b benana
>>>
```

I want to say:

```
if param == 'a':
    print value # Here I want the value of `a` key only!
```

I want to print `apple` only.

Comment: what is wrong with `li.get(param)` or `li.get('a')` ?

Comment: .. or just `li['a']` ?

Comment: Do you have only one parameter you want to get or multiple?  Are you sure that the parameters are going to be in the dictionary?  Basically, what are you actually trying to do here?  Maybe there's a better way. . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use:

```
li['a']

>>> li = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'benana', 'c': 'cherry'}
>>> li['a']
'apple'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dict.get(key[,default])`

```
li.get('a', None)
```

you can check if key is present, then fetch the value:

```
if key in li:
    li[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if param == 'a':
    print(li[param])
```

Or if you want to be extra sure:

```
if param == 'a' and param in li:
    print(li[param])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
li = {'a': 'apple', 'b': 'banana', 'c': 'cherry'}
param = 'a'
print (li[param])
```